WildFly, JBoss using unicast
I have 11.0 Wildfly. I found JGroups TCP Socket Binding Configuration: https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_data_grid/7.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/configure_jgroups#binding_a_group_of_sockets_example
I made it but ALWAYS in logs I get [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) ISPN000088: Unable to use any JGroups configuration mechanisms provided in properties {}. Using default JGroups configuration!
I did try all steps that was in documentation. I want to use UNICAST instead of multicast because my nodes are in the different subnets (in my case in different FW). But I always get 'using default jgroups' and in the wireshark there is UDP trafic.
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
            <cache-container name="keycloak" jndi-name="infinispan/Keycloak">
                <local-cache name="realms">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="users">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="sessions"/>
                <local-cache name="authenticationSessions"/>
                <local-cache name="offlineSessions"/>
                <local-cache name="clientSessions"/>
                <local-cache name="offlineClientSessions"/>
                <local-cache name="loginFailures"/>
                <local-cache name="authorization">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="actionTokens"/>
                <local-cache name="work"/>
                <local-cache name="keys">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="1000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="server" aliases="singleton cluster" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="default">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <invalidation-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </invalidation-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"/>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="tapi-container" aliases="sfsb2" default-cache="tapi-cache" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" jndi-name="infinispan/tapi-container" statistics-enabled="true">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="tapi-cache" jndi-name="infinispan/tapi-container/tapi-cache" mode="ASYNC">
                    <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:5.0" default-stack="tcp">
        <channels default="ee">
            <channel name="ee" stack="tcp"/>
        </channels>
        <stacks>
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="TCPPING">
                    <property name="initial_hosts">192.168.4.22[7600],192.168.4.23[7600]</property>
                    <property name="num_initial_members">2</property>
                    <property name="port_range">0</property>
                    <property name="timeout">2000</property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2">
                    <property name="use_mcast_xmit">false</property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
            </stack>
        </stacks>


You are linking Red Hat Data Grid documentation while you seem to be running Keycloak version that was based on WildFly? Can you actually have a look what software you are indeed running?

Yes I run keycloak based on WildFLy. Actually, I run apiman.

In WildFly, to change the JGroups channel used by an individual Infinispan cache container, use the following CLI command, updating the resource names accordingly:
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=web/transport=jgroups:write-attribute(name=channel,value=tcp)

If you are actually running Keycloak, refer to this guide -https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching - where you find out that switching the JGroups stack for Infinispan is done by --cache-stack=tcp.

So according to keycloak documentation there is no way to use UNICAST?
Quote: "tcp
TCP
MPING (uses UDP multicast)."

And I can't use kc.sh because The kc.sh script is typically part of a standalone Keycloak distribution, not directly bundled within WildFly. So I need to write in standalone-apiman-full-ha.xml. But when I write directly stack, got an error:
416: 
|                                   ^^^^ 'stack' isn't an allowed attribute for the 'transport' element
|
|                                        Attributes allowed here are: channel, lock-timeout, stack

In a typical 'tcp' jgroups stack, you are using TCP for nodes communication, thus unicast, and MPING is only used for automatic member discovery.

It's always best to use CLI for editing resources so you get validation immediately without having to refer to the XSD.

Can you provide me config that do NOT use multicast at all. My nodes are in different cities. My KeyCloak version is 3.4.3. How can I make keycloak to use unicast?

Михаил, the stack that is defined in your XML file that you posted is already 100% TCP-based stack with no UDP traffic. So if you are only using caches that are defined in that file, they are already using TCP traffic only. The software you are running is probably creating/starting caches elsewhere. Can you enumerate what specific (WildFly-based) software and version you are running?
